# Python : Trying to convert resultant and angle to original i and j values.

Tags: python, vector, angle

Im trying to get python to take a resultant value and angle value to return the original i and j values of a vector. I can get it to go from i and j values to resultant and angle but it is tricky the other way around.

```
    #vector conversion (x,y) to resultant and angle#
import math

menu = input('Vector Conversion: for vector to (x,y) press 1. \n                   for (x,y) to vector press 2.')
if menu == '2':
    user_distancex = float(input('What is the distance in x-direction?'))
    user_distancey = float(input('What is the distance in y-direction?'))

    r = (math.sqrt(user_distancex**2 + user_distancey**2))  
    theta = math.atan(user_distancey/user_distancex)*(180/math.pi)

    print(r, 'feet',theta, 'degrees')
elif menu == '1':

    user_angle = float(input('What is the angle of your vector?'))
    user_resultant = float(input('What is the distance (resultant) of your vector'))
    x_dist = user_resultant*math.cos(math.degrees(user_angle))
    y_dist = user_resultant*math.sin(math.degrees(user_angle))
    print((x_dist,y_dist))
```

Comment: What's tricky about it? Do you not get the correct result?

Comment: no what I did should have worked based on what my calculator does but, this gives back different values. I test with 45 degrees and distance of 2.82843. which should be about 2 and 2 for x and y. but it gives back -1.6,2.27

Comment: Vector Conversion: for vector to (x,y) press 1. 
                   for (x,y) to vector press 2.1
What is the angle of your vector?45
What is the distance (resultant) of your vector2.8284271247462
(-1.673899166908771, 2.279925783665376)
>>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`math.degrees(user_angle)` converts your user angle from radians to degrees. But it is already in degrees if the user inputs it in degrees!

You should use `math.radians(user_angle)` instead.

It also helps to clarify your input prompt:

```
user_angle = float(input('What is the angle of your vector (in degrees)?'))
```

Comment: sorry... really new to this didn't know accepting and answer was a thing.